# How to add banner in android application for android version-10

Tags: android

I have developed a simple android "Banner" application to display banner but I have a problem in my "Banner" application.

When I run the application on my android phone that uses Android version-10, it runs successfully, but in banner area (area reserved for to display banner) there is red color text which is "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."

Banner.java

```
   import com.google.ads.*;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyBannerActivity extends Activity {



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());


    }
}
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">




  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Banner Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ifahja.banner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyBannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>



            <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"/>

        <!-- android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" -->    



    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check my code I will be waiting for your response.

Comment: Please clear me about the two tags android:value="a149afxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"/>